# alias vs empty new extending class

Tags: c++

Edit 2:

Ok so i might rephrase the question, is there a differense between an empty extending class and its base class, apart from beeing a different type? Like is the memory-size the same, and are they functionally equivalent?

---

Is there any difference in the compiled code and/or performance of this completely empty class definition versus an alias? Or does this depend on the compiler, in which case, it it likely to be optimised away?

```
class MyClass : MyTemplateClass<int>{};
using MyClass = MyTemplateClass<int>;
```

I want to use the class definition so I can forward declare it and avoid a circular dependency more easily.

---

The circular dependency:

Master.h

```
class Master {
    void run();
    State s;
}
```

State.h

```
class State {
    void Modify(MyClass&);
}
```

MyTemplate.h

```
template<typename T>
class MyTemplateClass<int> {
    void run(Master* pMaster) {
         pMaster->run();
    }
};

using MyClass = MyTemplateClass<int>;
```

"State.h" needs "MyTemplate.h" to be included, "Template.h" needs "Master.h" to be included, and "Master.h" needs "State.h" to be included, completing the circle. If MyClass was not an alias but an actual class, State would not need to include the template and can forward declare MyClass.

Comment: One of these defines a type, the other does not.   They really aren't comparable.  The class definition requires the full class definition of the type it inherits from, so it leaves you in the same predicament you are already in.  A 'using' declaration (in this form) is just syntactic sugar and does nothing that simply typing out the name on the right side wouldn't do.  It seems likely you are confused as to what forward declarations do and when they are useful, but without further context, I can't give you any suggestions on the correct path forward for the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: In my case it lead to a much nicer way of solving the circular dependancy.

Comment: XY problem. If you want to avoid a circular dependency you could just forward declare `MyTemplateClass`.

Comment: I do not want to forward declare the MyTemplateClass since its a rather big template and then i'd have to alias the same thing multiple times.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Forward declaration and circular dependency have nothing to do with aliasing.

Comment: You don't automatically get constructors when you inherit from a class, AFAIK.  So if your parent type isn't default constructible, you're in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<class T> struct MyTemplateClass {};

class MyClass1 : MyTemplateClass<int>{};

using MyClass2 = MyTemplateClass<int>;


int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(MyClass1).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(MyClass2).name() << std::endl;
}
```

example output:

```
8MyClass1
15MyTemplateClassIiE
```

Different types.

Comment: I dont care that they are different types, i need no casting between them or any generics. I just need it to not slow down when defining an empty class instead of aliasing. The template is a sort of factory to generate classes which are not interchangable.

Comment: @BartVerberne I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. You mentioned forward-declaration earlier. Can you modify the question to demonstrate the kind of problem you are having?